# AccessViolationException calling native C++ code from managed C++ (wrapper for ASP.NET)

Tags: c++, managed-c++

I have a ASP.NET web application that needs access to a function in a native C++ DLL. To do this, I wrapped the native C++ code using a managed C++ DLL. Calling the native function from the managed code, however, results in a `System.AccessViolationException`. I do not have to the native code, but it will write to the file system (logs), which was my first guess, but according to other SO answers the `AccessViolationException` is caused by memory issues.

The code is pretty simple, this is the unshortened version:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

#define AS_NATIVE_STRING(managed_string) msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managed_string)
#define AS_MANAGED_STRING(native_string) msclr::interop::marshal_as<String^>(native_string)

ReturnStruct ManagedClass::execute_managed(String ^param1, String ^param2)
{
    auto param1_native = AS_NATIVE_STRING(param1);
    auto param2_native = AS_NATIVE_STRING(param2);

    // here I get the exception:
    auto result = _wrapped_api->execute_native(param1_native, param2_native);

    if (is_error_string(result.first))
        throw gcnew System::Exception(AS_MANAGED_STRING(result.second));

    auto result1 = AS_MANAGED_STRING(result.first);
    auto result2 = AS_MANAGED_STRING(result.second);
    return ReturnStruct(result1, result2);
}
```

Any hints on what could be causing it? I did indeed look at similar questions, but no answer seemed to really fit my problem.

Edit:
Using `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` I was able to determine the error message of the `AccessViolationException`: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: Try using std::wstring instead of std::string.

Comment: This is not really an option as the wrapped code does only accept `std::string` and I cannot change that. In addition to that, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp the conversion between `std::string` and `System::String^` is valid. Yes, i could probably convert from `System::String^` to `std::wstring` and then to `std::string`, but I would rather not like to touch `std::wstring`, so could you tell me your reasoning behind the suggestion? Is it just a wild guess or a founded suggestion?

Comment: Just that String is made up of 16-bit chars.  OK if you're keeping to the std ASCII set but anything outside that and you are into utf-8/wchars etc.  Is this code in its own file or is it part of a big managed C++ code?  The managed/unmanaged stuff normally needs to be in a separate source file.  I've never found out the reason but that normally works.

Comment: That might be true, but I just verified, that the marshalling to multibyte strings also works with non-ASCII characters, or to basically: this works as is. The whole DLL consists of only 6 functions that mix managed and native code, so yes, you could say that they are in a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I have come to the conclusion, that I basically cannot fix this on my end. I created a mock version of the DLL myself to be able to step in and see if the type conversion is correct and the parameters contain the correct strings. This was the case. This does not really help me, but maybe someone else might find a problem in his/her code with this approach.

I will just contact the authors of the wrapped api.